# sharing X axis between d3 charts in angular

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, data-visualization

I am adding D3 line charts to a page using an ng-repeat in angular. Within the ng-repeat is a chart directive that uses data from the ng-repeat.

I am adding data to the ng-repeat dynamically based on an ng-click. This works great, but I need all of the charts to share the same X axis. I need the X axis to be updated when data is added and removed from the ng-repeat.

Current Code of my directive:
Basically, I will need to set the X axis for all charts in the ng-repeat based on dates within stackedChartData rather than each individual chart.

```
<div ng-repeat="chart in stackedChartData">
    <stacked-chart chart-data="chart.list" x="date" y="value"
                  width="600" height="270"
                  margin="{top: 40, right:20, bottom:50, left:40}"></stacked-chart>
  </div>


    function StackedChartController($scope, $element, $attrs){
        this.x = $scope.x;
        this.y = $scope.y;
        this.xLabel = ($scope.xlabel || capitalize(this.x));
        this.yLabel = ($scope.ylabel || capitalize(this.y));
        this.height = $scope.height;
        this.width = $scope.width;
        this.margin = $scope.margin;
        this.data = $scope.chartData || [];
        this.xScale = null;
        this.yScale = null;
        this.svg = null;

        this.svg = d3.select($element[0])
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", this.width)
            .attr("height", this.height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")");


        this.innerWidth = this.width - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
        this.innerHeight = this.height - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

        $scope.$watch("chartData", (function(newVal, oldVal) {
            this.data = newVal;

            this.xDomain = (typeof $scope.xdomain === 'function' ? $scope.xdomain : xDomainCommand);
            this.yDomain = (typeof $scope.ydomain === 'function' ? $scope.ydomain : yDomainCommand);
            // Redraw the graph after new data loads.
            this.drawAxes();
            this.append($scope.lines || [], this.data);
            this.plotData(this.data);
        }).bind(this));

        /* Debugging
         $scope.$watch("ydomain", (function(newVal, oldVal) {
         console.log('ydomain', newVal, oldVal);
         }).bind(this));
         */

        var x = this.x,
            y = this.y;

        var xDomainCommand = function(data, d3){
            data = data || [];
            return [d3.min(data, function(d) {
                return d[x];
            }), d3.max(data, function(d) {
                return d[x];
            })];
        };

        var yDomainCommand = function(data, d3){
            data = data || [];
            return [
                ((d3.min(data, function(d){
                    return d[y];
                }) - 1)),  (d3.max(data, function(d){
                    return d[y];
                }) + 1)
            ];
        }

        // Setting these methods to default functions.
        // But these will often be override by different scopes
        // which need to be able specify different different functions
        // for caclulating the data ranges.
        this.xDomain = xDomainCommand;
        this.yDomain = yDomainCommand;
    }


    /**
     * Plotting the data (an array of objects) passed to the function.
     * @param data
     */
    StackedChartController.prototype.plotData = function(data){
        data = data || [];
        var xScale = this.xScale.bind(this);
        var yScale = this.yScale.bind(this);
        var x = this.x;
        var y = this.y;
        var valueline = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) {
                return xScale(d[x]);
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return yScale(d[y]);
            });

        // Add the valueline path.
        this.svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline(data));

        // Add the points
        this.svg.selectAll("dot")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr("cx", function(d) {
                return xScale(d[x])
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {
                return yScale(d[y]);
            })
            // Tooltip
            .append("svg:title")
            .text((function(d){
                if (typeof this.tooltip === 'function'){
                    return this.tooltip(d)
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }).bind(this));
    };


    /**
     * Sets the size of the graph (range) and max/min values to plot (domain)
     */
    StackedChartController.prototype.setParams = function(){

        // Set the ranges
        this.xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0, this.innerWidth]);
        //xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
        this.yScale= d3.scale.linear().range([this.innerHeight, 0]);
        // Scale the range of the data
        this.xScale.domain(this.xDomain(this.data, d3));
        this.yScale.domain(this.yDomain(this.data, d3));

        // Define the axes
        var axisGenerators = {};
        axisGenerators.x = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.xScale)
            .orient("bottom").ticks(5);
        axisGenerators.y = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.yScale)
            .orient("left").ticks(5);
        return axisGenerators;
    };


    /**
     * Adds extra lines beyond the initial one created by the initial dataset.
     *
     */
    StackedChartController.prototype.append = function(lines, data){
        data = data || [];
        var xScale = this.xScale.bind(this);
        var yScale = this.yScale.bind(this);

        lines.forEach(function(item){
            var valueline = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) {
                    return xScale(d[item.x]);
                })
                .y(function(d) {
                    return yScale(d[item.y]);
                });

            this.svg.append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .style("stroke", item.color || 'black')
                .attr("d", valueline(this.data));

            if (item.showPoints === true) {
                this.svg.selectAll("dot")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter().append("circle")
                    .attr("r", 5)
                    .attr("cx", function (d) {
                        return xScale(d[item.x])
                    })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) {
                        return yScale(d[item.y]);
                    })
            }
        }, this);
    };


    /**
     * Clears the graph before redrawing the axes.
     */
    StackedChartController.prototype.drawAxes = function(){
        var svg = this.svg;

        // Remove original lines drawn on the axes.
        // PF (2016/03/04) This is interfering with multiple datasets.
        svg.selectAll('*').remove();

        var axisGenerators = this.setParams();


        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.innerHeight + ")")
            .call(axisGenerators.x);
        // text label for the x axis

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(axisGenerators.y);
    };


    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            x: '@',
            y: '@',
            height: '=',
            width: '=',
            margin: '=',
            chartData: '=',
            tooltip: '=',
            lines: '=',
            xdomain:'=',
            ydomain: '='
        },
        template: '<svg></svg>',
        controller: StackedChartController
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating a separate array of dates that all of the charts use for their x domain.

Every time a new item is added to the chart ng-repeat, their dates are also pushed into another array that is sorted by date.

I set up a $watch in the directive that looks at the date array and redraws all the graphs when this array changes

**Directive watch**

```
$scope.$watch('at', (function (newVal, oldVal) {
            this.xDomain = $scope.xdomain;
            this.yDomain = (typeof $scope.ydomain === 'function' ? $scope.ydomain : yDomainCommand);
            // Redraw the graph after new data loads.
            drawAxes();
            plotData(this.data);
            append($scope.lines || [], this.data);
            $compile($element)($scope);
        }).bind(this));
```

I needed to access data outside of the scope of the directive so I used this syntax below for my parentData

**Directive scope**

```
scope: {
            x: '@',
            y: '@',
            height: '=',
            width: '=',
            margin: '=',
            chartData: '=',
            at: '=parentData', // used to access outside scope
```